# Page loads three times on Google Chrome (Mac)

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-chrome, http-headers

Check out this page: http://tinyurl.com/chrome-loads-thrice.

When accessed via Google Chrome (OSX, 37.0.2062.122), it loads three times. The number you see is the number of times the page has loaded.

The first load give me 1, the second load gives 3, then 5, 7 , 9, 11...

It looks like this in code:

```
session_start();

$count = isset($_SESSION['test_counts']) ? $_SESSION['test_counts'] : 1;
$_SESSION['test_counts'] = $count + 1; 

printHeader();
echo '<p>'.$_SESSION['test_counts'].'</p>';
printFooter();
```

I can't give the contents of those functions, but you can see their output. Without printHeader and printFooter, the page loads with normal counts.

Comment: IE creation you start with 1 then add 1 (=2), reload =3.

Comment: Sounds like `printHeader` and `printFooter` are incrementing the session variable. I don't see any indication that my browser is loading the page multiple times. You can look in the Network tab of Developer Tools to see what's being loaded.

Comment: I have set a breakpoint in PHP's debugger, it is called exactly three times.

Comment: The test_counts index has never existed before today and is not incremented anywhere else. Can you confirm the counts as I said?

Comment: My only guess is something to do with the headers and something to do with the html, but it must be a bug with Chrome. Note that Safari loads this page fine, ie. 1,2,3,...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug in Google Chrome. It looks like they are working on it.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=420070

Comment: is there any solutions?

Comment: They confirmed it as a bug 12 days ago, but it is low priority.